# How do I know what ports are on my Macbook?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to go through this particular code example from "The Well Grounded Rubyist" regarding TCPServer and threads. The code is below:

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new(3939)
connect = server.accept
connect.puts "Hi. Here's the date."
connect.puts 'date'
connect.close
server.close
```

How do I know what port is on my Macbook? The docs has `2000` in the example. However, when I try both of these numbers the code doesn't execute, it continues to hang indefinitely.

How can I check if these numbers are verified ports? I tried telnetting to the port number and the connection is refused everytime.

Comment: The reason this hangs is because it is waiting for connection. Your mac, as every other machine, do have port 3939.

Comment: Wikpedia's "[List of TCP and UDP port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)" might be good for you to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.accepts` waits for a client to connect to the server. If that does not happen, it just keeps waiting. Run the code, then open terminal and type:

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 3939
```

At this point you will create TCPSocket, which will connect with your server. This will cause  the rest of the code to execute. You can check it with your socket:

```
while line = s.gets # Read lines from socket
  puts line         # and print them
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply BroiSatse. This did the trick. One last thing, can I insert any number onto the TCP.new constructor?

Comment: Ports below 1024 are usually reserved for some services, like 80 is reserved for html, 443 for https and 22 for ssh to name just a few. In practice network ports are just a numbers (16-bit numbers) and there are no hardware sitting behind those (unlike computer ports).